# Custom word2vec Transformer on pandas dataframe and using it in FeatureUnion

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, pipeline, word2vec

For the below pandas DataFrame `df`, I want to transform the `type` column to OneHotEncoding, and transform the `word` column to its vector representation using the dictionary `word2vec`. Then I want to concatenate the two transformed vectors with the `count` column to form the final feature for classification.

```
>>> df
       word type  count
0     apple    A      4
1       cat    B      3
2  mountain    C      1 

>>> df.dtypes
word       object
type     category
count       int64

>>> word2vec
{'apple': [0.1, -0.2, 0.3], 'cat': [0.2, 0.2, 0.3], 'mountain': [0.4, -0.2, 0.3]}
```

I defined customized `Transformer`, and use `FeatureUnion` to concatenate the features.

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline, FeatureUnion
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

class w2vTransformer(TransformerMixin):

    def __init__(self,word2vec):
        self.word2vec = word2vec

    def fit(self,x, y=None):
        return self

    def wv(self, w):
        return self.word2vec[w] if w in self.word2vec else [0, 0, 0]

    def transform(self, X, y=None):
         return df['word'].apply(self.wv)

pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('features', FeatureUnion(transformer_list=[
        # Part 1: get integer column
        ('numericals', Pipeline([
            ('selector', TypeSelector(np.number)),
        ])),

        # Part 2: get category column and its onehotencoding
        ('categoricals', Pipeline([
            ('selector', TypeSelector('category')),
            ('labeler', StringIndexer()),
            ('encoder', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')),
        ])), 

        # Part 3: transform word to its embedding
        ('word2vec', Pipeline([
            ('w2v', w2vTransformer(word2vec)),
        ]))
    ])),
])
```

When I run `pipeline.fit_transform(df)`, I got the error: `blocks[0,:] has incompatible row dimensions. Got blocks[0,2].shape[0] == 1, expected 3.`

However, if I **removed** the word2vec Transformer (Part 3) from the pipeline, the pipeline (Part1 1 + Part 2) works fine.

```
>>> pipeline_no_word2vec.fit_transform(df).todense()
matrix([[4., 1., 0., 0.],
        [3., 0., 1., 0.],
        [1., 0., 0., 1.]])
```

And if I **keep only** the w2v transformer in the pipeline, it also works.

```
>>> pipeline_only_word2vec.fit_transform(df)
array([list([0.1, -0.2, 0.3]), list([0.2, 0.2, 0.3]),
       list([0.4, -0.2, 0.3])], dtype=object)
```

My guess is that there is something wrong in my `w2vTransformer` class but don't know how to fix it. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is due to the fact that the FeatureUnion expects a 2-d array from each of its parts.

Now the first two parts of your FeatureUnion:- `'numericals'` and `'categoricals'` are correctly sending 2-d data of shape (n_samples, n_features).

`n_samples` = 3 in your example data. `n_features` will depend on individual parts (like OneHotEncoder will change them in 2nd part, but will be 1 in first part).

But the third part `'word2vec'` returns a pandas.Series object which have the 1-d shape `(3,)`. FeatureUnion takes this a shape (1, 3) by default and hence the complains that it does not match other blocks.

So you need to correct that shape.

Now even if you simply do a `reshape()` at the end and change it to shape (3,1), your code will not run, because the internal contents of that array are lists from your word2vec dict, which are not transformed correctly to a 2-d array. Instead it will become a array of lists.

Change the w2vTransformer to correct the error:

```
class w2vTransformer(TransformerMixin):
    ...
    ...
    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        return np.array([np.array(vv) for vv in X['word'].apply(self.wv)])
```

And after that the pipeline will work.